# CHECK CONSTRAINT on foreign column

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table for `Person`s that have a birth date, a table for `Event`s that have happened on a specific date and a table describe which person `Participate`d in which event, is it possible to constraint who participated in what event by ensuring that their birth date occurred before the event's date?

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
    IDP int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    BIRTH date;

CREATE TABLE Events
    IDE int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    WHEN date;

CREATE TABLE Participants
    IDP int,
    IDE int,
    CONSTRAINT pk_participants PRIMARY KEY(IDP, IDE),
    CONSTRAINT ref_idp FOREIGN KEY(IDP) REFERENCES Persons(IDP),
    CONSTRAINT ref_ide FOREIGN KEY(IDE) REFERENCES Events(IDE),
    CONSTRAINT person_existed CHECK (???);
```

I'm wishing to put in the `person_existed CHECK` expression something like `Persons(BIRTH) < Events(WHEN)` but that obviously didn't work with `BIRTH` being an invalid identifier. Is what I'm after at all possible ?

I'm using SQLDeveloper 4.1.1.19.

Comment: As a constraint, no.  You could create triggers on all three tables that attempt to enforce the constraint (and that, say, prevent you from changing when an event occurred if that would violate the rule).  That tends to get a little messy though.  You could create a materialized view that does a fast refresh on commit and shows all the rows where the event happened before the participant was born (a query that should return 0 rows) and put a constraint on that materialized view that will always fail.

Comment: You could do this without a trigger, but it would require populating the two dates in `Participants` -- which makes maintaining that table tricky.  A trigger might be your best option.

Comment: What you describe here is a multi-row/multi-table check constraint. This is a SQL construct known as an assertion. However, Oracle does not yet support these constructs (and nor do any of the other main RDBMS products. You can find out more [Here](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4390732/sql-assertions-declarative-multi-row-constraints). In the meantime, triggers and/or materialized views are the best ways of approximating assertions.